# pgfplots: How can I set x-domain between data points?

Tags: pgfplots

I am plotting a piecewise-linear curve from a data file. I would like the x-domain to start and end at points that are between the x points in the data file so that the curve ends at or below the top of the y-axis.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
30, 74.296
31, 67.289
32, 61.924
33, 58.271
34, 56.347
35, 56.118
36, 57.504
37, 60.384
38, 64.61
39, 70.018
40, 76.436
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines=left,
            scaled ticks=false,
            xtick=\empty,
            ytick=\empty,
            xmin=30,
            xmax=39,
            ymin=50,
            ymax=68,
            extra x ticks={32,36,37}, 
            extra x tick labels={$r+1$,$r+Q$,\kern25mm{$r+Q+1$}},
            clip=false, 
        ]

        \addplot[restrict x to domain=30:39] table [col sep=comma] {data.dat};

        % arrow to x tick
        \draw[->] (axis cs:37.6,49.3) -- (axis cs:37.1,49.7);

        \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Resulting figure:

[image]

What I want is more like this:

[image]

It seems natural to do something like

```
\addplot[name path=gy,restrict x to domain=30.5:38.5]
```

but that just truncates the x range at the nearest actual data points, i.e., 31:38, which is too narrow for what I need.

I created the second figure by setting `clip=true`. But the problem with that approach is that the little arrow below the x-axis disappears too since it's being drawn outside the axis. (Or maybe there's a different way to get that arrow?)

Thanks in advance, folks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `clip mode=individual` instead of `clip=false`. This will activate clipping for the plots, but not other stuff drawn with e.g. `\draw`.